# Batch file to execute a Powershell script

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have a Powershell script which converts a CSV file to Excel, however I want to create a Batch file to execute that Powershell script. When I try to I get an error message:

```
error processing aurguments. there is no option with the following name: execution policy.
Syntax
powershell_ise.exe[[-File] <listoffiles>][-Help]-[MTA][-Noprofile]
```

The Batch file script is:

```
@echo off
Powershell_ise.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\Users\siddhary\Desktop\csv_to_xlsx .ps1
```

however when I open the `Powershell_ise.exe`, then open the script from desktop & run, it runs succesfully. But when I try to do it with a batch file I get the above error message.
Please help.

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. That option isn't supported. http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847883

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong.  Powershell_ise.exe does not accept an -executionpolicy parameter.  You can verify this yourself by running:

```
powershell_ise.exe /?
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your call from powershell_ise.exe to powershell.exe

```
@echo off
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\Users\siddhary\Desktop\csv_to_xlsx .ps1
```

Here's the reference to using [powershell_ise.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj571645.aspx), and here's [powershell.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx)

Comment: You have used the `_ise` version in your example.